# How do you format Web Reporting pivot table data?

Tags: mdx, olap, iccube

By default, setting up a pivot table via the web reporting package seems to display data in some float format. Is it possible to truncate decimals, or insert commas where appropriate for large numbers? Or how can we format a decimal into a percentage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For formatting cells you've two different options :

1) You can use MDX (this includes float formatting & colors). See [FORMAT_STRING](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/cellProperties/FORMAT_STRING.php) and [Cell Properties](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Cell%20Properties.php) for all options ( [CLASSNAME](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/cellProperties/CLASSNAME.php) example is worth checking ).

2) You can also define in the reporting : Widget / Columns / Cell Renderer / Format ...

Hope it helps